# Limsup of a sequence smaller than $x$

Tags: random-variables, limsup-and-liminf

Let $X_n$ be a sequence of random variables. Show that:

$$ \{\limsup X_n < x\} = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{ m =n }^{\infty} \{ X_m < (x - (1/x)) \} $$

**First question** :the def of limsup says that it is the intersection of the union. I don't get why above the final statement is written as the union of the union of the intersection. 
**Second question**: I don't know where the first Union going from k to inf comes from. 
**Third question**: What's the " 1/x" and how is it  interpretable?

Comment: Where is the variable $k$ used in $\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty?$

Comment: It was an exercise given by my professor at the exam, so idk. I think that instead of 1/x, he meant 1/k and so it is where it comes from.

Comment: We can only guess what your professor is asking. As written, it is unclear what $x$ is and what $k$ is doing there. The right side is a set, the left side is a random variable, so it is unclear how one can be less than the other.

Comment: No, the Xm is a sequence too. x is a value, so there are no sets

Comment: The right side is a set. Intersection and union are operations on sets.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This was the statement at the exam, any suggestion?

Comment: Again, we can't make sense of notation which has no standard meaning.

Comment: I'd guess the left side is supposed to be shorthand: $$\limsup_{n\to\infty} \{\omega\in \Omega\mid X_n(\omega)<x\},$$ where $\Omega$ is your sample space, and thus the left hand side is limsup or sets, and hence a set.

Comment: And I'd guess that $x-1/x$ is supposed to be $x-1/k.$ But this is all guessing.

Comment: For the first thing, i think you're correct. I re-wrote the statement with brackets. On the 1/k that was even my thought. What could be the solution if your guessing would be correct?

Comment: As you've rewritten it, I think the left side now means: $$\{\omega\in\Omega\mid (\limsup X_n(\omega))<x\}$$ where this limsup is a limsup of real numbers, rather than a limsup of sets. But again, only guessing.

Comment: Ok, but now suppose, just to have a starting point, that you're suggestions are correct. How woudl you procede?

Comment: In general, if $a_n$ is a sequence of real numbers, then $\limsup a_n<x$ if and only if there is $K$ such that for all $k\geq K,$ there are only finitely many $n$ such that $a_n\geq x-1/k.$ Seems like this would probably be related, but I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't think so because if this would be true for all K, this means for the intersection but in the statement there is the union

Comment: If it is true for one $k,$ it is true for all bigger $k,$ but not all $k.$ Don't confuse $K$ with $k.$

Comment: Got it. What about the question one?  The lim sup is usually written as the Intersection of the union of the sequence. In the final result, since the first Union starting from k is for the "1/k", there is the union of the intersection, which is usually the result of the liminf. I can't get why they are inverted

Answer (score 1):

The correct statement should be
$$ \{\limsup X_n < x\} = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{ m =n }^{\infty} \{ X_m < (x - \frac{1}{\color{red}{k}}) \}\,. $$

- An $\omega\in\Omega$ is in the RHS if and only if there exists a $k\ge 1$ and an $n\ge 1$ such that for all $m\ge n$
  $$
  X_m(\omega)<x - \frac{1}{\color{red}{k}}\,.
  $$
- This is equivalent to saying that
  $$
  \limsup_nX_n(\omega)<x\,.
  $$

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to show the proof?

Comment: The proof uses nothing but the definition of limsup which says -as @ThomasAndrews already commented- that only finitely many $m$ are not below $x-1/k$.

Comment: but why in the proof m=n and in you def m is greater than n? And second point, what is this 1/k?

Comment: The lim sup can be written as the intersection of union, instead here is written as the union of intrsection, why?

Comment: First: I am not saying that $m$ is *greater* than $n$. I am saying $m\ge n$. In the intersection $m$ starts at $n$ and runs to $\infty$. What is that to you compared to $m\ge n$ ? What is this $1/k$ ? A number strictly greater than zero. Lastly: edit your question and write the limsup as an intersection of union and we discuss.

Comment: Ok thanks for the first two answers. About the last: The lim sup is usually written as the Intersection of the union of the sequence. In the final result, since the first Unione starting from k is for the "1/k", there is the union of the intersection, which is usually the result of the liminf. Hope is clear

Comment: It is not. If you disagree with my answer I expect yours to be formalized.

Comment: I'm sorry but i'm not disagreeing with you, i'm just trying to understand, instead i'm really appreciating what  you're saying. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3376571/confusion-about-definition-of-limit-of-infimum-and-supremum-of-a-sequence-of-set in this question there are the def of liminf and limsup, so i thought that them should have been in the final result

Comment: It is getting a little late in the evening here. What I see quickly in this link is that that OP asks about liminf limsup of *sets*. They are different from liminf limsup of *sequences*. Here in this post we have expressed a statement about the limsup of a *sequence* by unions/intersections of sets. That's all.

Comment: I'm not getting the differences, but ok. Thank you!

Comment: The limsup of a sequence of numbers $a_n$ is its largest point of accumulation. The limsup of a sequence of sets $A_n$ is the set of those elements that belong to infinitely many sets $A_n$. Two different concepts . We are even talking about different things we take the limsup of. The motivation for this nomenclature probably comes from $\liminf a_n\le \limsup a_n$ and $\liminf A_n\subseteq\limsup A_n$. Neat isn't it ?