# Sequence of random variables and liminf

Tags: calculus

Let Xn be a sequence of random variables. Show that:

$$ \{\liminf X_n > x\} = \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{ m =n }^{\infty} \{ X_m > (x + (1/k)) \} $$

My procedure was,
from the definition of liminf:

**Exist** a k>1 and **exist** a n>1 such that **for every** m>n: $\{ X_m > (x + (1/k)) \}$

But in this case I'd have :
$$ \bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty} \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} \bigcap_{ m =n }^{\infty} \{ X_m > (x + (1/k)) \} $$ and so i got the union and the intersection in the reverse place.

I don't know how to reach the results I wrote at the beginning.

Comment: Hint: use $-\liminf X_n=\limsup(-X_n)$ and apply what we know from your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4549821/949989). This will also reveal some errors in this new question.

Comment: This hint should be used in the fact that the LHS is included in the RHS or viceversa?

Comment: I more more or less agree with you (in your last formula, it should be $x+\frac{1}{k}$ and not $x-\frac{1}{k}$). Indeed, suppose $(x_n)$ is a convergent sequence. Then $$\lim_{n\to \infty }x_n>x\iff \exists k\in\mathbb N,\exists N\in\mathbb N:\forall n\in\mathbb N,  n\geq N\implies x_n> x+\frac{1}{k}...$$ what I would translate as : $(x_n)$ is far away from $x$ from a certain rank $N$.

Comment: @GabrielePillitteri . The last formula is now correct and the first one just wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limsup of a sequence smaller than X](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4549764/limsup-of-a-sequence-smaller-than-x)

Comment: What about: w ∈ liminf {Xn > x} : ∃k>1, ∃N>1 : ∀m≥n,  w ∈ {xn>x+1/k}, but if w is in the liminf and the latter is in the limsup, I proved the first conclusion. In the other way around, I can simply write that x ∈ limsup for a certain K, I rewrite the latter as "-liminf(-Xn), I proceed as before and I'm showing both inclusion, so LHS and RHS are the same.

Comment: @KurtG. I didn't get. The first formula in my question was the final result of the exercise. The last one was my solution, but in this one I showed that the final result would have been the limsup.

Comment: If you agree with the limsup formula you only have to remember that $-Y>x$ is equivalent to $Y<-x$ . Plug in $Y=\limsup(-X_n)$ and you are done.

Comment: What about my proof i wrote above?

Comment: Congrats. Looks good. First formula is wrong. Given exercise might be wrong.

Comment: But if the right answer was what I wrote, so liminf is the union of the union of the intersection, in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4549764/limsup-of-a-sequence-smaller-than-x , you told me that limsup was the same. So now, what is correct?

Comment: Are you again confusing liminf limsup of sequences with those of sets ?

Comment: So, sorry for the misunderstanding, in this exercise about liminf, the correct result is union of union of intersection of union of intersection of union?

Comment: Union of Union of Intersection. For liminf and limsup of sequences of Numbers . In aeternum amen.