# Show that $M\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{j=n}^{\infty}\left\{ f_j(x)-f(x)>\frac{1}{m}\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, limsup-and-liminf

> Let be $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ a sequence of functions, with $f_n:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$. We define $M:=\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid \liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)> f(x)\right\}$. Show that
> \begin{align*}
> &M\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{j=n}^{\infty}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f_j(x)-f(x)>\frac{1}{m}\right\}.
> \end{align*}

---

Let's choose an arbitrary $x\in M$ and assume $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)-f(x)=\delta>0$. WLOG we assume $\delta$ to be rational otherwise we find a $r\in\mathbb{Q}$ such that $0<r<\delta$. We know that $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)$ is a limit point so that we find infinitely many $k\in\mathbb{N}$ with $\liminf\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)-f_k(x)<\frac{\delta}{2}$. Hence, we find infinitely many $k\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $f_k(x)-f(x)>\frac{\delta}{2}$. So
$$
x\in \bigcup\limits_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{j=n}^{\infty}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid f_j(x)-f(x)>\frac{1}{m}\right\}.
$$

---

Is this correct?

Comment: Does this (applied to $X_n=f-f_n$ and $x=0$)  answer your question? [Limsup of a sequence smaller than $x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4549764/limsup-of-a-sequence-smaller-than-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct but I believe that in the end you mixed up some indices. So let $x \in M$ and $\liminf_{n \to \infty} f_n(x) = \delta + f(x)$ for some $\delta>0$. This means that a subsequence $(f_{n_j}(x))_j$ converges to $\delta + f(x)$. This means: For every $n \in \mathbb N$ we find a $j \ge n$ with $\lvert f_j(x) - f(x) \rvert > \frac{\delta}{2}$.
This shows
$$x \in \bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{j=n}^\infty\{x \in \mathbb R: \lvert f_j(x) - f(x) \rvert >\frac{\delta}{2}\}$$

Now there is $m \in \mathbb N$ such that $\frac 1m \le \frac{\delta}{2}$ because $\lim_{m \to \infty} \frac 1m =0$. This implies
$$x \in \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty\bigcap_{n=1}^\infty \bigcup_{j=n}^\infty\{x \in \mathbb R: \lvert f_j(x) - f(x) \rvert >\frac{1}{m}\}$$

Comment: Which indices did I mix up?

Comment: When you say "we find infinitely many $m$" this is true as far as I believe. But from a statement like this you can't end up at the union $\cup_{m=1}^\infty$ because that corresponds to "we find one $m$".

Comment: Oh I unerstand what you mean. This was a bit sloppy, I should have introduced a new index. I have edited my question. I hope this makes it clear.

Answer (score 1):

In fact much more is true:
$$M=\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{j=n}^{\infty}\left\{x\in\mathbb{R}\,\left|\,f_j(x)-f(x)>\frac1m\right.\right\}.$$

- Proof of $\subset$: let $x\in M.$ Then, for some $m\ge1,$ $\liminf f_n(x)-f(x)>\frac1m,$ i.e.
  $$\exists n\ge1\quad\forall k\ge n\quad\inf_{j\ge k}\left(f_j(x)-f(x)\right)>\frac1m.$$
  This implies $\forall j\ge n\quad f_j(x)-f(x)>\frac1m.$
- Proof of $\supset$: let $x\in\Bbb R$ be such that for some $m,n\ge1,$ for all $j\ge n,$ $f_j(x)-f(x)>\frac1m.$ Then
  $$\forall k\ge n\quad\inf_{j\ge k}\left(f_j(x)-f(x)\right)\ge\frac1m.$$
  This implies $\liminf f_n(x)-f(x)\ge\frac1m,$ hence $x\in M.$
- Proof that the equality above is "much more" than the requested inclusion: for any sequence $(A_n)_n$ of sets,
  $$\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcap\limits_{j=n}^{\infty}A_j=\liminf A_n\subset\limsup A_n=\bigcap_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{j=n}^{\infty}A_j.$$

Comment: Two minor remarks. 1.) regarding the proof of $\subset$: Note that if $\exists n\ge1\quad\forall k\ge n\quad\inf_{j\ge k}\left(f_j(x)-f(x)\right)>\frac1m$ then by definition of infimum we already get *strict* inequality, i.e. $\forall j\ge n\quad f_j(x)-f(x)>\frac1m$. 2.) regarding the proof of $\supset$: if $\liminf f_n(x)-f(x)\ge\frac1m$ then $\liminf f_n(x)-f(x)>\frac{1}{m+1}$ and that's why $x\in M$.

Comment: Thank you @Philipp I shall improve 1). I shall not change 2) since $\liminf\ge\frac1m$ directly proves that  $\liminf>0.$